How to design SQL Schema for identical product components in product bundles
I'm in the process of designing a schema in our MySQL database to properly link products and product components. This is fairly straightforward using a product and product_components table design. However, there is one challenge I'm facing in the design.
This challenge relates to the fact that we have many different products that are interchangeable. To provide context DVD sets are one of our products. For something like "Chronicles of Narnia 1-3", we may have several instances of the 1st film in our product table. These products may have little to no physical difference but will have different UPCs.
Because these products are the same our warehouse treats them as essentially the same item when we receive them. I've created two tables inventory_sync_group and inventory_sync_group_products to allow us to identify and properly track inventory for products like this.
I'll provide a picture of an example of real data in my proposed schema. Please note in particular the Chronicles of Narnia (1st Film) records in the product table and how they are associated with an inventory_sync_group.
My main challenge is determining how best to define a product as a product_component if it is interchangeable with various other products, or in other words, if it is associated with an inventory_sync_group.


This design looks ideal. If the product_id is in the inventory_sync_group you then have options for product substitution.

If someone wants all 3 films and you are out of the series (1-3) copies. do you want to offer 3 separate products as a substitution? In that case you need a way to specify multiple products for 1  inventory_sync_group row. maybe add a sub product index

Perhaps add sync group to your product_components.  If a sync group is defined, then you know you need to get a listing of the available product ID's from the sync group instead as "there are options" to fill the order or what not...  you can have a procedure which evaluates component_ids in the table agains those in a sync_group and u pdate accordingly.... or don't worry about it.  At time of fulfilment; simply evaluate the component to see if it's in a sync group if it is find the one with the "most/least" inventory and return its ID to be picked...

@BartMcEndree To your question, the answer would be no. We list these on Amazon so anything that we bundle ourselves would be listed separately from a singular "series" type product that contains all the DVDs in one case. Hopefully that makes sense.

Usually however they have a  different SKU/UPS because there's added footage, or different box; or something.  So to say they are the same... isn't entirely true right? if the box is different and you're including images you may get negative feedback if you provide a different "Box"...  Some of the differences may have limited runs which could add value as well.  Just food for thought...  Think comic book with different artwork and limited runs. maybe that will help.

@xQbert I think you've honed in on essentially where I'm stuck in the design. As Bart said above, I think the current design actually works fine. The main concern I have is that atm its arbitrary which product_id is stored in the product_components table for anything that's part of a sync group and it isn't immediately apparent that it's a "synced" product type. Not a major issue but I feel I might be leaning towards putting the sync_group_id into the product_components table.

@xQbert that is also correct. The way we operate to my understanding is only certain products are interchangeable for certain sets. There is a design question there that I'll be sorting out soon with some operations folks, but for now just focused on the basic design here

@kliuyyyy My off the top of head remains:  add sync_group to product_componets.  Either component_ID is populated or the sync group; never both.   If a sync group is listed, then you have to determine "Which one" to include based on rules (FIFO, LIFO, Least cost, Quantity etc).  The issue I forsee is a new UPC comes in which now requires a new syncgroup fro an existing component.  A job needs to run in the database to check to see the new sync group components are already listed in product_components, and if there is; component is nulled out and syng grroup ID is added.

@xQbert I believe anytime a sync group is created I could manage the functionality of ensuring any included components in product_component get updated with the ID of the sync group and have component_id nulled. Is that also what you're thinking?

Yes that was what I had in mind as well.  So either Componet_ID is populated or the sync_group_ID is populated on product_component
